# MVVM multiple textboxes one command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I have four of the same `StackPanel`s in a Grid Layout. (See one of them below)

Is it possible to implement this easier?

How I can get all values or changes from `Textbox`es in the `StackPanel`(s)?

Is it possible to bind one `Command` in the panel to get the changes in the `ViewModel`?

I think the answer is anything with `ItemControl`?!

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="50, 90, 0, 0" Height="auto" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
      <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80"/>
      <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="60"/>
    </Style>
  </StackPanel.Resources>
  <Label Content="2" Width="60" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
  <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
  <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
  <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
  <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I don't see commands and `TextBox` don't have one. You probably mean event (`TextChanged`?) and its easy to subscribe all `TextBox`es to the same event and use `sender` in the handler to identify which one it is. Subscribing automagically would be even more code-behind, probably not worth it. To have command you need to use one of MVVM libraries with event to command support.

Comment: See xaml behaviors https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/wiki